# Solving for the Logistic Regression Coefficients

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have been searching for a source on how to compute the coefficients for logistic regression, but haven't found any. I suppose it is very easy to find like linear regression.

Can you kindly suggest a source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no "closed form" expressions that parallel those for linear regression i.e.
no equivalent of
$$
\hat{\beta}=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T y
$$
The coefficients for logistic regression are found numerically from maximum likelihood equations. There are plenty of references available e.g. [this](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf) or [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote06.html)